# Pass parameters to program started with Runas

Tags: windows, command-line, command-line-arguments, runas

I am trying to start Performance monitor as different user. I found `runas.exe` but syntax for program arguments makes me go crazy.
The following syntax works:

```
C:\Windows\System32\runas.exe /user:domain\username perfmon.exe
```

But since `perfmon.exe` has the argument `*/res*` the following line doesn't work:

```
C:\Windows\System32\runas.exe /user:domain\username perfmon.exe /res
```

I tried to escape `*/res*` but without any success. I tried:

```
"/res"
\"/res\""
\"\/res\""
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The correct syntax is to include both the target executable and its parameters in double quotes like this:

```
runas.exe /user:domain\username "perfmon.exe /res"
```

```
runas.exe /user:domain\username "perfmon.exe \"argument with spaces\" /res"
```

---

More Information: [Runas command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc771525(v=ws.10))

Answer (score 4):

For anyone stumbling upon this while searching for a way to use `runas` with an application **where its own parameters may contain spaces.**

The original accepted answer with `\"` did **not** work for me.

What works is to put a **double quote** to actually be able to pass arguments with spaces:

```
runas.exe /user:domain\username "perfmon.exe ""argument with spaces"" /res"
```

It is actually explained quite nicely here: https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html